# Wordpress querying wrong database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, migration

We have a site that was a development version at test.mydomain.com. I migrated it to www.mydomain.com. I exported the existing database, created a new one, imported, then changed the wp_config file to point to the new DB and changed siteurl and homeurl values. However, in wp_options (phpmyadmin) the values for siteurl and home continue to be test.mydomain.com. I can log into the Wordpress admin on mydomain.com but it's searching for post data in test.mydomain.com and not populating the posts in the editor.

Comment: before import the database you can open it on a text editor like Notepad++ then replace the test.mydomain.com with mydomain.com then save then the database import.

Comment: Isit imperative do do it before the import? I thought that those database values get taken from the wp_confiig file?

Comment: yes it works you can do it

Comment: going to settings > permalinks and just without changing anything press save changes, this will refresh your rewrite rules. It's a good practice to do this after moving databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the .htaccess file then go to the permalinks page change to another permalink that is not selected this should force a .htaccess file to be created then you can change back. This might not work but as you have changed your database settings in the mysql I don't see why it will look at the old site url/database.

Install adminer plugin for wordpress this will let you change the database from the plugin and will allow for changing of the fields that did not change to point to my domain.com ..

Answer (score 0):

Memcached (specifically object-cache.php in wp-content) is most likely at fault, just de-activate it